# Batch File - Ignore CLS in sub Batch Files

Tags: batch-file

I'm creating a batch file that will call a few other batch files.  One of the batch files to be called has a "CLS" in it.  Is there some way I can get the wrapping batch file to ignore the child "CLS" call while still letting the CLS work when the child batch file is called directly from the command line?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is a real ugly hack :-)

The CLS screen command does not work if `stdout` is redirected to `con:` - it prints the Form Feed character (0x0C) to the screen. On my machine it looks like the female symbol.

```
@echo off

:: Normal call, CLS in called batch clears the screen
call batch2

:: Redirected call, CLS in called batch prints <FF> character to screen (without newline)
call batch2 >con:
```

Advantage - No need to modify your child script.

Disadvantage - The unwanted `<FF>` character appears in the output.

Answer (score 2):

Hmm - quite how long **IS** a piece of string?

Generally, you could try this in your `CALL`ed batch:

```
@echo off
setlocal
set skipcls=%1
if defined skipcls (if "%skipcls%"=="::" (shift) else (set "skipcls="))
...
%SKIPCLS% cls
...
```

Then call your batch with an extra first parameter `::`

If the first parameter is `::` it will be shifted out and `skipcls` will be set to `::`; otherwise `skipcls` will be empty, hence the `%skipcls% CLS` line will be skipped or executed...

---

Amendment:

Perhaps

```
@echo off
setlocal
if "%~1"=="::" (shift&set "skipcls=REM ") else (set "skipcls=")
...
%SKIPCLS% cls
...
```

would be simpler. Setting `skipcls`to a value of REM<kbd>SPACE</kbd> rather than `::` would allow the technique to be used more reliably within parenthesised constructs.

Of course, another approach would be to set `skipcls` appropriately in the caller routine.

OR set `skipcls` to any non-empty value you like and use

```
if [not] defined skipcls ...
```

which supports constructs like if it's set do this, if not do that.

And of course, it's not restricted to `CLS`, so perhaps a different variable name should be used.

And if you're really feeling adventurous, you could set `redirect` to `>>"a_filename"` in the caller and then have

```
%redirect% ECHO whatever
```

to steer output to an externally-controled destination.

Seems to be many ways to apply a simple concept.

Comment: The user wants to know how to avoid ignore the `cls` without manually doing this: if he wanted to do this he could just do `Ctrl + H` in notepad and replace `cls` with `Rem cls` or `:: cls`. Further more, why should he bother doing this since typeing `%SKIPCLS%` is much longer and prosaic when compared to `::` or `rem`. A `-1` from me.

Comment: @Monacraft - At least Magoo's solution is parametized. The same script can be called with CLS enabled or disabled without having to change the code; just the CALL needs to change. But it is simpler to optionally define variable CLS as CLS or undefined. Then simiply use %CLS% in the body of the script.

Answer (score 1):

You could create a temp batch file, where all `cls` commands have been ingnored:

```
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
set target=targetname.bat
for /f "usebackq delims=" %%a in ("%target%") do (
set line=%%a
Echo !line:cls=Rem Cls! >> temp_%target%
Echo !line:CLS=Rem Cls! >> temp_%target%
Echo !line:Cls=Rem Cls! >> temp_%target%
Rem Include CLs ClS cLS, etc. if the person who wrote the file is not case consistent
Rem  : ( 
set line=
)
call temp_%target%
set target=
Endlocal
```

And that should do what you want perfectly.

Mona